# my button click to return the next page object is showing the error module object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have started using the page object model in my automation script for our website.  I am using Python, Webdriver
I have a LoginPage class with some methods
I have a AdministrationPage class with a method.  (When user has logged in the Administration page is shown)

On the Login page I have a method called clickAdministration(self):.  the button click is in here and the return is return Pages.administrationPage(self.driver)

When my code runs and it gets to the clickAdministration the following error is shown:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore \TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py", line 31, in test_add_Project
    administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration()
  File "C:\Users\riaz.ladhani\PycharmProjects\Selenium Webdriver\ClearCore \Pages\page.py", line 59, in clickAdministration
    return Pages.administrationPage(self.driver)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I need some help please, my syntax is incorrect for calling the Administration Page object when i click the Administraition button from the LoginPage class.

When i click the Administration link after the user has logged in (from LoginPage class) I should return the AdministrationPage object.

My LoginPage and AdministrationPage classes are in a Package called Pages
My TestCase Classes are in a Package called TestCases

Also you will notice in my code snippet my calls to WebDriverWait is commented out.  This is because I get a timeout exception when i use this.  I have reverted to using time.sleep for now.
If anyone can also help with my WebDriverWait syntax that would be helpful.
Thank you.

My code snipped as follows:

TestCases\AdministrationPage_TestCase.py

```
    import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Pages import page
from Pages.administrationPage import AdministrationPage
from Pages.page import LoginPage


class AdministrationPage_TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.45.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
        self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")
        self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        print "I am here in setUp self.login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)"
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def test_add_Project(self):
        login_page = page.LoginPage(self.driver)
        login_page.userLogin_valid()
        administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration()
        print "I am here administration_page = login_page.clickAdministration(self.driver)"
        administration_page.AdministrationPage.add_project()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Pages\administrationPage.py

```
import time
import datetime
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Locators.element import BasePageElement

class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class AdministrationPage(BasePage):
    # Add a project, enter project name & description, save
    def add_project(self):
        add_project_button = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.addButton_project)
        add_project_button.click()
        project_name_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.projectName_textfield)
        project_name_textfield.click()
        project_name_textfield.clear()
        dateNow = self.get_date_now()
        project_name_textfield.sendkeys('LADEMO_IE_nn_')
        project_description_textfield = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.projectDescription_textfield)
        project_description_textfield.click()
        project_description_textfield.clear()
        project_name_textfield.sendkeys("LADEMO create a basic project test script - Selenium Webdriver/Python Automated test")
```

Pages\page.py (This is the LoginPage class)

```
    import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
from Locators.locators import MainPageLocators
from Locators import locators
from Locators import element
from Locators.element import BasePageElement
import Locators
import Pages.administrationPage


class BasePage(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver


class LoginPage(BasePage):
    def click_go_button(self):
        element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.GO_BUTTON)
        element.click()

    def userLogin_valid(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        userName_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.usernameTxtBox)
        userName_textbox.clear()
        userName_textbox.send_keys("user1")
        password_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.passwordTxtBox)
        password_textbox.clear()
        password_textbox.send_keys("test123")
        submitButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.submitButton)
        submitButton.click()

    #Click Administration from top menu
    def clickAdministration(self):
        # getting Timeout exception when i use this, using sleep for now
        #WebDriverWait (self.driver, 10).until(lambda d: self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath).click()) 
        time.sleep(15)
        self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath).click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print "I am here, trying to click Pages.administrationPage"
        return Pages.administrationPage(self.driver)

    def user_login_invalid(self):
        userName_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.usernameTxtBox)
        userName_textbox.clear()
        userName_textbox.send_keys("user1")
        password_textbox = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.passwordTxtBox)
        password_textbox.clear()
        password_textbox.send_keys("test1")
        submitButton = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.submitButton)
        submitButton.click()

    #check if Administration link is present.  When logged in we can check are we on the correct page
    def isAdministration_present(self):
        #administrationLink = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath)
        #print "administrationLink = " + administrationLink
        #wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        #h3 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath))
        #h3.click()
        #print h3.text
        time.sleep(10)
        try:
            administrationLink_text = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath)
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return "Administration" in administrationLink_text.text # check if the text Administration is in the AdministrationLink_text, return true if it is
        #print "administrationLink_text.text = " + administrationLink_text.text


    def is_text_present(self):
        try:
            #body = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") # find body tag element
            administrationLink_text = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocators.AdministrationButton_xpath)
        except NoSuchElementException, e:
            return False
        return "Administration" in administrationLink_text.text # check if the text is in the Administration Link
```

Comment: `import Pages.administrationPage` exception message is not trying to fool you :) `from Pages.administrationPage import AdministrationPage` and `return AdministrationPage(self.driver)`. BTW, your imports section is a complete mess, clean it up a little

Comment: Thank you very much.  My colleague the developer said the same.  The dev said I should name my classes different to the module.  I will do this.I have it working now. If you move your answer to the answer section I will be able to tick it and vote up for you.